# Trigger Event automatically on DOMCharacterChanged or change on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

so basicially I have a `div` here which is `contenteditable` and a `button` on `click` of which the content of the `div` gets changed! Now what I want is trigger an `event` for `div` automatically once the content gets changed.

> Note: I am using jQuery version 1.8.2

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/e1gmvhpc/1/)**

I've tried like below but with no success.

```
<div contenteditable id="divtxt">First Text</div>
<button id="btnChange">Change</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#divtxt').bind("DOMCharacterDataModified",function(){
    alert('this is the event of div'); 
});
$('#btnChange').bind('click',function(){
   $("#divtxt").text('Text Changed on click');
});
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: what is issue here ? i get alert message when type in `contenteditable` div in your fiddle example.

Comment: sorry but cant understand . when i click on button it change content of div .

Comment: Yea!! See that time when content is changed the event is not triggered. That's the issue here. It should trigger automatically. @Zee has given an answer which works well but it would be helpful if it gets worked for the `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html()` instead of `text()`.

```
$('#btnChange').bind('click',function(){
   $("#divtxt").html('Changed on click');
});
```

Comment: Works like charm buddy! +1 for that!! But for some reason I've to avoid using `.html()` and have to use `.text()`. Will see! If I do not get solution for the same in next 2 or 3 hours, I will accept this answer. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao. another thing is [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) are deprecated and may not be supproted by all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the info and I was aware of that too, this works fine in IE. Need fix only for chrome and I hope chrome doesn't create any problems.. :)